# Cannot delete a project reference

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reference, project

I'm (unfortunately) working with an old, old website type Visual Studio project in VS 2010/2012, and I'm unable to delete a project reference. When I open up the Properties Page, highlight the reference I want to delete, and click remove - nothing happens.

I've tried it in both these versions of Visual Studio and tried running as admin, and it still doesn't work. This seems like a pretty idiot proof thing to do, but somehow I can't make it work.

Comment: You could always open the project file up in notepad and hand-remove the reference from the XML?

Comment: The old website project types don't have a project file. They were referenced in the web.config. I removed  them from there, and that seemed to work. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out (I think). The reference I needed to remove was in the web.config, and that file was write protected by source control. I checked out that file and manually removed the reference from the web.config. It is now gone.